# Saving data gives a error, param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I´m trying to save an input to my database using Angular and Rails. At the moment when the action is performed I get a `400 (Bad Request)` error in the console log and the Rails error is as following,

```
Started POST "/movies.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-24 07:57:09 +0200
Processing by MoviesController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"titles"=>"Star", "movie"=>{}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: title):
  app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:24:in `movie_params'
  app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Routes.rb

```
resources :movies, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
end
```

The search.html.haml template used, here a user should input the title.

```
#addMovie{"ng-controller" => "addMovieCtrl"}
  %div{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
    %input{:type => "text", "ng-model" => "title"}
    addMovie action.
```

My movieController.js, this is the action that fires when a user clicks on the div in the `#addMovie`

```
angular.module('addMovieseat', ['ui.router', 'templates'])

  .controller('addMovieCtrl', ['$scope', 'movies',
    function($scope, movies){
      $scope.movies = movies.movies;

      $scope.addMovie = function(){

        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
        movies.create({
          titles: $scope.title,
        });
        $scope.title = '';
      };
    }
  ])
```

The angular service,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('movies', ['$http', function($http){
    var o = {
      movies: []
    };

    o.create = function(movie){
      return $http.post('/movies.json', movie).success(function(data){
        o.movies.push(data);
      });
    };

    return o;

  }])
```

And the movies_controller.rb

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_with Movie.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with Movie.create(movie_params)
  end

  private
  def movie_params
    params.require(:movie).permit(:title)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
 movies.create({
   titles: $scope.title,
 });
```

to

```
 movies.create({
   title: $scope.title,
 });
```

Ultimately, you need your parameters to look like this:

```
Parameters: {"movie"=>{"title"=>"Star"}}
```

Comment: Changing `titles` to `title` indeed fixed the `400 error`. When I do the save action and look at the movies.json file it says `[null,null,null,null]` so the title isn't being saved yet? Just en empty input? Where do I change those parameters you suggested?

Comment: hmm.. open up `rails console` and type `Movie.last`. If you see something in there that looks correct, then it is saving properly. If you see something similar to `ActiveRecord Association []` or a Movie record with `title: nil` then it's not saving properly. If it is saving properly, then there is a problem with the json output.

Comment: You are right, the title is being saved correctly. So there's a problem with the JSON output. Going to look into it. Thanks.